# 'From Action' and 'To action' missing in Navigation Rule tab of faces-config.xml visual editor

Tags: eclipse, jsf, navigation

[image]

I am using JSF in Eclipse and in the faces-config.xml file I click on the Navigation Rule. I have two files, login.xhtml and welcome.xhtml. I drag both of these from the project explorer into the Navigation Rule window. I select Link from the palette, and create a link from the login.xhtml to welcome.xhtml. I then select 'Select' from palette and I click on the arrow that is connecting both files.

Then when I click on the Properties View (where the server and console view are), I am supposed to see two text boxes named 'From Action' and 'To action'. But I only see textboxes 'display name' and 'description'.

How can I see From Action and To Action?

EDIT: I am using JSF 2.2. The tutorial that I'm reading uses JSF 2.0, if that makes a difference.

Thanks

Comment: You better edit the question again and add Eclipse version info and jsf (webtools)  plugin info

Comment: This is not a JSF provided feature. This is an IDE provided feature.